# How to display opportunities on GMap?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, map

I want to display a list of opportunities that exist in a report on GMap. I could not find any free app @ AppExchange.

My idea was the following:
1. Create a csv export from Reports
2. Convert on [CSV2KML](http://kmltools.nobletech.com/csv2kml)
3. Import in GMaps

However, I have a problem with `Billing Address`.
For GMap to display the address, I need at least `Billing ZipCode` and `Billing Country`.

So I tried to concetanate these boths fields, with a custom field, but this fails as in fields there is only one global `Billing Address`.

What would be a workflow to show opportunities on GMap?

Comment: What GMap do you mean? Take a look at this, maybe it will help: http://salesforceapexcodecorner.blogspot.de/2012/06/multiple-address-on-visualforce-page.html

Comment: This SO post shows some code examples that may help you if you want a DIY solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122038/how-do-i-integrate-salesforce-with-google-maps

Comment: @jkraybill I can't believe how far this piece of code has "traveled". It all started as an internal workshop material to educate colleagues from Java team "look guys, Salesforce is cool, you can do mashups of your data with Google Map without any server-side code" ;)